# Why am I seeing two identical payments associated with one contribution in 4.7.x?

Tags: civicontribute, lts, iats

"Is this an issue with iATS payments Extension?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No it's not** an issue with the iATS Payments Extension.

I got this question - and have reproduced it using 4.7.7 and iATS Payments Extension [note the transaction IDs are identical]:

[image]

But I also get this on the 
http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute?reset=1
[today May23 at 9:40MT] - again: note the transaction IDs are identical:

[image]

I will file a JIRA issue for this - Please note that iATS Extension is officially still on the 4.6.x (LTS = Long Term Release).

Comment: Done: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18661

Comment: Did you mean to write that you reproduced the issue on 4.7.7 with the dummy processor? I reproduced it with the dummy processor as well.

Comment: I did write that :-)

Comment: Glad you were able to reproduce it too (note I added my repro screenshot on demo)